# mapping javascript files to a typescript definition file

Tags: typescript

I am trying to add type tests to a javascript project that only has an `index.d.ts` and type tests written in typescript.  The rest of the "real" project is written in vanilla js.

My tests look a bit like this:

```
import { expectType } from 'ts-expect';
import {create} from 'src/file';

describe('Any', () => {
  it('creates something', () => {
    const a = create();
    expectType<Something>(a);
  });
});
```

The problem is, `import {create} from 'src/file';` will resolve to the actual physical file and infer the types from the javascript file.

I would like to somehow tell the compiler to  use the `index.d.ts` file for these definitions.

I want to do something like this which most definitely does not work:

```
  "paths": {
    "src/*": ["index.d.ts"],
    "*": ["./node_modules/@types/*"]
  }
```

Here is the whole `tsconfig.json` but I don't know how to map the declaration file to the javascript files:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
      "module": "commonjs",
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "lib": [
          "es6"
      ],
      "noImplicitAny": true,
      "noImplicitThis": true,
      "strictNullChecks": true,
      "types": [
          "mocha"
      ],
      "noEmit": true,
      "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
      "allowJs": true,
      "baseUrl": ".",
      "paths": {
        "src/*": ["src/*"],
        "src/*": ["index.d.ts"], // somehow map the js types to the ts types
        "*": ["./node_modules/*"]
      }
  },
  "include": [
      "types/**/*.test.ts"
  ]
}
```

The only way I've got this to work, is to change the import to this:

`import {create} from 'package-name';`

And then `npm link` the project so it thinks it is a dependency of itself.

Is there a better way?

Comment: can you post your entire `tsconfig.json` file?

Comment: @KlasMellbourn I've added the tsconfig.json but I don't think it is that relevant